# Querying data between a specific date and time in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, querying

I have a database in access where every data has a date and time in two different columns.

I need to to run a query in excel using VBA which would fetch me data between two specific dates and times (eg: 01/05/2016 13:15 and 03/05/2016 10:11)

My query is as follows:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM " & database & " WHERE symbol='" & companyName & _
      "' AND AdmitDate BETWEEN " & (fromDate + fromTime) & " AND " & (toDate + toTime) & ""
```

However, it gives me a syntax error which says:

> 'Missing operator in query expression'

I am not able to figure out where I have gone wrong.

Please help!

Comment: If the date and time are split into different columns in your database you should run two separate `BETWEEN` statements e.g.  `"AdmitDate BETWEEN " & FromDate & " AND " & toDate & " AND AdmitTime BETWEEN " & FromTime & " AND " & toTime` - Also how are your dates stored in the database? What format?

Comment: Hi! I guess this would not work. For example, if I need data from 01/01/2016 10:00 to 01/03/2016 13:00. Running two separate statements would only give me data from 10:00 to 13:00 for the given days! It would not fetch data which is not between 10:00 and 13:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the right string expressions for the date/time values. Format can create these:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM " & database & " WHERE symbol='" & companyName & "' AND AdmitDate BETWEEN #" & Format(fromDate + fromTime, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "# AND #" & Format(toDate + toTime, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
```

Comment: Never mind my edit suggest I got some learning to do formatting time.  Thanks

Comment: @JohnWFowler: No problem.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot